# Key exchange algorithm for Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, networking, encryption, cryptography

Following this [github issue](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/9463), almost none of the KEX cryptos are available for Xamarin.
The only KEX that is working is RSACryptoServiceProvider but it is INCREDIBLY slow.
 Are there any alternatives?

Comment: *"The only KEX that is working is RSACryptoServiceProvider"* - RSA is ***key transport***, not ***key exchange***. In *key exchange*, both parties contribute material to the shared secret. In *key transport*, one party selects the key and sends it to the other party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the EC25519 implementation of Hans Wolff ([Source](https://github.com/hanswolff/curve25519)).
Warning: The NuGet DLL is not build for android so you have to build it yourself.